# is Ubuntu portable and independent of the installed enviremonet?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to install a Ubuntu core to a SD card. Now can I use this SD card for the different PCs or for a Xinlin board?. is Ubuntu portable?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use a recent kernel with all the required drivers, it should work quite well. This is basically the same way Live CD's of different distributions work. You will run into problems when you have to use different architectures, so you can't run an AMD64 Ubuntu on an ARM board, for obvious reasons.